# search tuples object in UIsearchbar?

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, uisearchbar

I have an object act as tuples called StackholderTokenAndFormBalances and rendered it is data in UItableView. I want to add UIsearchbar to view data inside the object for example if user search token it will view the token property. on the other hand,  if he writes a form name it will view form data.
  how I can achieve the in searchBar func?

```
struct StackholderFormBalances{
    let forms:[FormForm]
    let formStakeholderBalance:[[FormStakeholderBalance]]

}

struct StackholderTokenAndFormBalances{
    let tokenBalance:Int
    let stackholderFormBalances:StackholderFormBalances?
}
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredStackholderTokenAndFormBalances = searchText.isEmpty ? stackholderTokenAndFormBalances : stackholderTokenAndFormBalances. { (item: String) -> Bool in
           return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
       }

       tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have two array one is arrDuplicateStocklist . it's use for filter..
and other is arrStockList array. it's use for main array.

```
self.arrDuplicateStockList = self.arrStockList.filter({
        ($0.QID).range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
            ($0.QNAME).range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
```